# Why excel returns #Value! when in TEXTJOIN function one cell exceeds 252 characters?

Tags: excel

So i am using TEXTJOIN function in excel and it works great, unless one of the cells which should be joined contains more than 252 characters.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ";TRUE;IF($A$1:$A$20=C1;$B$1:$B$20;""))
```

So,for example, if cell B2 has 255 characters, it will give me a #VALUE! error.

If the textjoin is without IF function, it works fine even if cells contain more than 252 characters. Why it is so and is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: I believe this was changed to 32767.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c

Comment: Just a Stab in the dark, (I'm out)  but could he not try instead  a search within search ? Nested search?  Non matches would result in na.???

Answer (score 3):

This is because the "IF" function only allows cells that have less than 253 characters. If you took the "TEXTJOIN" out, the "IF" would produce a "#VALUE!" error.

Comment: I had tried to use My excel 2016 VBA udf textjoin in exact same  way And came across same issue. It just occurred to me now nested searches might be a way around it. Idk. I'm out now but will give it a try